# Internet Explorer 6 Z-Index

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

please take a look at the following website: http://www.solidcamxpress.co.uk/

If you look at it in IE6 (try IE Tester if your running Vista or 7) you will notice that the dark grey masthead appears behind part of the panel, and the top of the main image is chopped off. I'm guessing this is a problem with the z-index which IE6 and 7 are notorious for having problems with.

Can anyone help me fix this? need it for the client asap. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is the infamous "ie6 z-index bug". It has been discussed a couple of time on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/z-index) and on the [web](http://www.google.com/search?q=ie6+z-index+bug).

Personnaly, the best resource that I found for this bug is [Solutions to the IE z-index Bug: CSS](http://mahzeh.org/?p=19). It clearly describe the bug and the solution.

By the way, questions like "Look at my site and please tell me how to fix it" are better answered on [doctype.com](http://doctype.com/).

Comment: Yeah I've read lots of articles about this sort of thing. But as far as I can tell the site is correct? So not sure why they are appearing behind the others?

Comment: As a note, doctype.com closed as of February 15, 2013. [Read more about it](http://blog.doctype.com/doctype_is_closing_on_the_14th_1).